# How does QAOA choose its result from samples when there are degenerate states

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms

When there are multiple samples corresponding to the same (minimum) energy and with the same probability, how does qiskit pick the final result?

In my experiments, if I check all samples, I can see there are 32 states all having the minimum energy and the same probability,
[image]

And the QAOA solver will output results like this, which seems it picks the first one as the final result.

[image]

The question is, how is this order decided? and why qiskit chooses the first one as the final result, even other samples have the same energy and probability?

Comment: Welcome to QCSE! Please post output as text in the [markdown codeblock](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-format-code-in-markdown/) instead of an image so it will be easier to read. Also, include your code if possible.